# how to use GlideModule on Glide 4?

Tags: android, android-glide

I recently update my app to use Glide 4, to be precise, Glide 4.2.0. 
gradle:

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.2.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.2.0'
compile ('com.github.bumptech.glide:okhttp3-integration:4.2.0'){
    exclude group: 'glide-parent'
}
```

in manifest:

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.xxx.MyGlideModule"
            android:value="GlideModule"/>
```

GlideModule class:

```
@GlideModule
public class MyGlideModule extends AppGlideModule {

    @Override
    public void registerComponents(Context context, Glide glide, Registry registry) {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build();

        OkHttpUrlLoader.Factory factory = new OkHttpUrlLoader.Factory(client);

        glide.getRegistry().replace(GlideUrl.class, InputStream.class, factory);
    }
}
```

how I use glide inside an adapter:

```
        RequestOptions myOptions = new RequestOptions()
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_placeholder)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
                .dontAnimate()
                .skipMemoryCache(true)
                ;

        Glide.with(mContext)
                .load(Imageid[position])
                .apply(myOptions)
                .into(imageView);
```

with these code, when I run it I got error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Expected instanceof GlideModule, but found: [my app package].MyGlideModule@d1c2328
  at com.bumptech.glide.module.ManifestParser.parseModule(ManifestParser.java:81)
  at com.bumptech.glide.module.ManifestParser.parse(ManifestParser.java:43)
  at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.initializeGlide(Glide.java:193)
  at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.checkAndInitializeGlide(Glide.java:172)
  at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.get(Glide.java:156)
  at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.getRetriever(Glide.java:540)
  at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.with(Glide.java:566)
  at [adapter line where I implement Glide]
```

how can I use MyGlideModule ?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

**Glide 4.0 need not** have declare "GlideModule" in **AndroidManifest.xml**. You just need to following steps:

1. **YourGlideModule** extends **AppGlideModule**, you can override function `applyOptions` in the **YourGlideModule** class.
2. You should make project in "android studio -> build -> make project", it will generate the `GlideApp` class.
3. Use the GlideApp such as `GlideApp.with(this).load(imgUrl).into(glide_test_iv1)`

Comment: thanks, your method works. they should add this to their doc. in readme or migrating section.

Comment: @Dika I use Glide 4.7.0 .Should I define this class?

Comment: Don't forget to mark your glide module with the '@GlideModule' annotation.

Comment: So many hours lost because of the manifest declaration left in the migration between Glide 3.x to 4.x... You saved my day Kevin !

Comment: i do build > make project. But no GlideApp class exists.

Comment: @chitgoks it happened to me cause my glide module was written in kotlin but I used "annotationProccessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0' ". I replaced it with kapt and it works ok now.

Comment: Non of above worked for me. @A.Kazarovets i also have same situation and use kapt.

Comment: YourGlideModule where to use this class ?

Answer (score 4):

If `GlideApp` can't be generated then -

Make sure you have `build.gradle` dependency of `annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'`

Make sure your `UnsafeOkHttpGlideModule` extends `AppGlideModule` and also in `meta-data`  the `android:value=""` should be `android:value="AppGlideModule"`

Answer (score 4):

Adding in @kevin & @brady lee answers.
For Kotlin Users

```
 implementation ('com.github.bumptech.glide:okhttp3-integration:4.4.0'){
    exclude group: 'glide-parent'
}
kapt  'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.10.0'
```