# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to find GlideModule implementation

Tags: android, android-glide

I want to use **Glide4** in my App, and I wrote some code reference online tutorial, but an error appeared:

```
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.zhiyun.mirror, PID: 7481
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.zhiyun.mirror/com.zhiyun.mirror.mxg.activity.HappyMainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to find GlideModule implementation
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2666)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2727)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1478)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6121)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:795)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to find GlideModule implementation
        at com.bumptech.glide.module.ManifestParser.parseModule(ManifestParser.java:68)
        at com.bumptech.glide.module.ManifestParser.parse(ManifestParser.java:46)
        at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.initializeGlide(Glide.java:228)
        at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.initializeGlide(Glide.java:219)
        at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.checkAndInitializeGlide(Glide.java:180)
        at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.get(Glide.java:164)
        at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.getRetriever(Glide.java:670)
        at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.with(Glide.java:697)
        at com.zhiyun.mirror.mxg.util.DreamGoImageLoader.displayImage(DreamGoImageLoader.java:13)
        at com.zhiyun.mirror.mxg.util.DreamGoImageLoader.displayImage(DreamGoImageLoader.java:9)
        at com.youth.banner.Banner.setImageList(Banner.java:354)
        at com.youth.banner.Banner.start(Banner.java:262)
        at com.zhiyun.mirror.mxg.activity.HappyMainActivity.initBanner(HappyMainActivity.java:178)
        at com.zhiyun.mirror.mxg.activity.HappyMainActivity.onCreate(HappyMainActivity.java:128)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6709)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2619)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2727) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1478) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6121) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:795) 
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.newear.base.glide.MyGlideModule
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:400)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:326)
        at com.bumptech.glide.module.ManifestParser.parseModule(ManifestParser.java:66)
        at com.bumptech.glide.module.ManifestParser.parse(ManifestParser.java:46) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.initializeGlide(Glide.java:228) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.initializeGlide(Glide.java:219) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.checkAndInitializeGlide(Glide.java:180) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.get(Glide.java:164) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.getRetriever(Glide.java:670) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.with(Glide.java:697) 
        at com.zhiyun.mirror.mxg.util.DreamGoImageLoader.displayImage(DreamGoImageLoader.java:13) 
        at com.zhiyun.mirror.mxg.util.DreamGoImageLoader.displayImage(DreamGoImageLoader.java:9) 
        at com.youth.banner.Banner.setImageList(Banner.java:354) 
        at com.youth.banner.Banner.start(Banner.java:262) 
        at com.zhiyun.mirror.mxg.activity.HappyMainActivity.initBanner(HappyMainActivity.java:178) 
        at com.zhiyun.mirror.mxg.activity.HappyMainActivity.onCreate(HappyMainActivity.java:128) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6709) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2619) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2727) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1478) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6121) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:795) 
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.newear.base.glide.MyGlideModule" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.zhiyun.mirror-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.zhiyun.mirror-2/lib/arm, /data/app/com.zhiyun.mirror-2/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:400) 
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:326) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.module.ManifestParser.parseModule(ManifestParser.java:66) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.module.ManifestParser.parse(ManifestParser.java:46) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.initializeGlide(Glide.java:228) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.initializeGlide(Glide.java:219) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.checkAndInitializeGlide(Glide.java:180) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.get(Glide.java:164) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.getRetriever(Glide.java:670) 
        at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.with(Glide.java:697) 
        at com.zhiyun.mirror.mxg.util.DreamGoImageLoader.displayImage(DreamGoImageLoader.java:13) 
        at com.zhiyun.mirror.mxg.util.DreamGoImageLoader.displayImage(DreamGoImageLoader.java:9) 
        at com.youth.banner.Banner.setImageList(Banner.java:354) 
        at com.youth.banner.Banner.start(Banner.java:262) 
        at com.zhiyun.mirror.mxg.activity.HappyMainActivity.initBanner(HappyMainActivity.java:178) 
        at com.zhiyun.mirror.mxg.activity.HappyMainActivity.onCreate(HappyMainActivity.java:128) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6709) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2619) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2727) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1478) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6121) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:795)
```

In my **build.gradle** in `base` module:

```
dependencies {
    api `com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.5.0`
    annotationProcessor `com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.5.0`
}
```

In my **build.gradle** in 'app' module:

```
dependencies {
    annotationProcessor `com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.5.0`
}
```

And My code in `app` module:

```
import com.bumptech.glide.annotation.GlideModule;
import com.bumptech.glide.module.AppGlideModule;

@GlideModule
public class MyGlideModule extends AppGlideModule {

}
```

Usage:

```
public void displayImage(Context context, Object path, ImageView imageView) {

        GlideApp.with(context).load(path).into(imageView);
}
```

I don't know why it happened, I have tried multiple variations of this, but none of them seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using flavors for your application?

Comment: Did you override ApplyOptions and RegisterComponents?

Comment: See this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46638056/how-to-use-glidemodule-on-glide-4

Comment: Are you missing manifest entry of glide module?

Comment: Write these: `implementation ‘com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.5.0’
annotationProcessor ‘com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.5.0’` in your app dependency and try.

Comment: Are you using proguard? if you are then you don't to write some rules for Glide module

Comment: @Ankita I tried it, but not work.

Comment: @AjayChauhan I don't  use **proguard**, and i reseted my code. Maybe my project had a error config with others not **Glide**

Answer (score 0):

i face the same problem when i upgrade the android studio , so for me , i use gradle 4.4 and for gradle plugin i use 3.1.4

```
 @GlideModule
   class GlideModule : AppGlideModule() {
   }
```

add this in your build.gradle

```
  implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
  kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
```

kapt in kotlin is like annotationProcessor in Java , the GLIDE module will be generated automatically

Comment: Thank you for your answer， but it isn't work for me. And i reseted my code.